# Continuous to discrete cut quartile in R from for loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, cut, quartile

I am trying to create a bunch of columns that are  quartile cuts based on multiple columns.  For example,

```
dataset[,412:422] <- NA

for( i in 50:60){
for(j in 412:422){
     dataset[,j] <- cut(dataset[,i], 
                                      breaks=unique(quantile(dataset[,i],probs=seq(.1,1,by=.1),na.rm=T)), 
                                      include.lowest=TRUE)
    } 
}
```

I want to create new columns 412 to 422 based on the binning of the continuous variables from columns  50 to 60.  When I try to do the above code all I get back is

```
   V412    V413    V414    V415    V416    V417    V418    V419 V420    V421    V422
(56,64] (56,64] (56,64] (56,64] (56,64] (56,64] (56,64] (56,64] (56,64] (56,64] (56,64]
 <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  <NA>    <NA>    <NA>


......

<NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA> <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Are you sure want a double loop here? You'll be assigning new values to the column `dataset[,j]` 11 different times. You really should also include a *minimal* [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data so we can run your code and test possible solutions.

Comment: I am a novice, so bare with me. I was thinking a double loop so that I could add columns to the existing data set.

Comment: You don't need a double loop for that. Again, provide a reproducible example and we can probably show you a better way.

Comment: The data set I am working with has over 19k rows, and over 400 variables. I think that would be too much to try and place here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is more about being organized and neat with your data. There are many ways to do this.

I would recommend separating out the data you want to bin into its own data.frame.

```
x=dataset[, 50:60]
```

then bin those columns into new columns by making a function with the parameters you want and using `apply`

function:

```
mycut=function(x)  cut(x, 
                       breaks=unique(quantile(x,probs=seq(.1,1,by=.1),na.rm=T)), 
                       include.lowest=TRUE)
```

apply:

```
xbin=apply(x,2,mycut)
```

Then putting xbin back into your dataset and appropriately name it.

Comment: I was way overthinking this!! Thank you!